# traceroute IPv6 using VB6

Tags: vb6, ipv6, traceroute

I try to perform traceroute using VB6, but don't have any idea how.

- I think of using dos to do the job, and then capturing the output of dos in my app.
- Another idea is to convert the address from ipv6 to ipv4 and then perform the trace route in case the hardware doesn't support IPv6

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randy Birch has details about how to [Perform a Tracert (Trace Route) in VB](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/internet/tracert.htm)  His article contains too much detail to post here, so just head over there and check it out.
His solution may appear verbose at first and it uses some/many API calls, but don't let that scare you off, it's all pretty straight forward once you read through it all step by step.

Edit: Sorry, I really should have read the question properly - I don't believe Randy's article will help you with any IPv4 vs IPv6 problems, but it will give you good place to start.